# pythonaddins module

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I've posted this question on GeoNet 4 days ago. At the moment I've received no answers and no comments so I thought I'd try here as well.

https://geonet.esri.com/activity#nPLoc=/inbox

I have a tool that works fine from My Tooboxes but we would prefer to run it as an addin button. I found GPToolDialog from the pythonaddins module would do the trick.

I set up the button OK and it runs fine when testing OnClick only using a straight forward script like zooming to selected and no pythonaddins methods.

When I tested the same button’s OnClick only using a one line pythonaddins function it wouldn’t work. Even pythonaddins.MessageBox wouldn’t work.

I thought I’d try running the code in the ArcMap Command Line window and it works fine from there.

My button script

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class ButtonClass1(object):

    """Implementation for Addin_Test_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(r'C:\Users\stazicd\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\My Toolboxes\PVP Zoom.tbx','PVPZoom')
```

Would any one know why it isn't working?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour], if you have not already.  Would you be able to **edit** your question to include a link to your GeoNet thread, please?  That way any potential answerers can check to see if there has been a recent answer before investing the time they volunteer here on a question that has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: posted comment on geonet

Answer (score 1):

As you can run your code (open a custom GP Tool) from within python window, then you toolbox path and its tool are ok.

It can be a problem with your config.xml. Check this file and look for the button and make sure the Class and id of the button are set to ButtonClass1. e.g:

```
<Button caption="GPToolDialog" category="Test Python Addin" class="ButtonClass1" id="LibraryName.ButtonClass1" image="" message="" tip="GP Tool Dialog"><Help heading="" /></Button>
```

Comment: Thanks Farid. Yep, my button ID is fine but that one was certainly worth checking.